# Show that $\frac{(J-1)!}{2!(J-3)!}= \sum_{h=2}^{J-1}(h-1) $

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

Could you help me to show that 
$$
\frac{(J-1)!}{2!(J-3)!}= \sum_{h=2}^{J-1}(h-1)
$$
where "$!$" denotes the factorial function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{h=2}^{J-1} (h-1) = \sum_{h=1}^{J-2} h = \frac{(J-2)(J-1)}{2}= \frac{(J-1)!}{2!(J-3)!}$$